# Dictionary not learning new words

Tags: dictionary, text-prediction

Since the last firmware update, my Android 4.3 phone is unable to learn new words.  It is not suggesting to me any new word that I previously typed, so I deduce that new words aren't being added to the dictionary.

From googling around it looks like it's a common problem, but I haven't found any solution so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you would find the same issue:
http://forums.androidcentral.com/sprint-samsung-galaxy-s4/364298-samsung-galaxy-s4-keyboard-can-t-remember-added-new-words.html

The solution is in the same post. I would cite it here:

> I think I may have found a solution. I recently had the same problem w/ my samsung galaxy s4 Active. I went into settings. I then hit the settings tool icon beside samsung keyboard. Made sure predictive text was on. I actually clicked it off then back on. Then I clicked on the word predictive text and under personalization there are a few learn options. I clicked learn from messages and learn from contacts. I just sent a message and it seemed to fix it! Please let me know if this helps any of ya'll!

Hope it help

Comment: I had tired the sane few days back...It works for a couple of messages and then back to the same problem